# Android MediaPlayer is Crashing on Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, crash, android-mediaplayer

I have this code in my app, I have used it for years, and it works on all versions of android from API 10 to API 22.

I upgraded my phone to API 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) and now it is crashing.

```
public static void beep(Context context) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

The error is:

> 01-29 17:16:20.641 8354-8651/mobiliza30.fyb E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>   01-29 17:16:20.643 8354-8354/mobiliza30.fyb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                 Process: mobiliza30.fyb, PID: 8354
>                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {mobiliza30.fyb/mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.utils.Utiles.beep(Utiles.java:573)
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte.buscarArticulo(ItemCbte.java:1544)
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte.agregarArticulo(ItemCbte.java:1009)
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte.access$200(ItemCbte.java:64)
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte$2.onEditorAction(ItemCbte.java:193)
>                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6038)
>                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5919)
>                                                                     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2654)
>                                                                     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9237)
>                                                                     at mobiliza30.fyb.activities.ItemCbte.onResume(ItemCbte.java:600)
>                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1281)
>                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6320)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Check lines in LogCat prior to the exception. `MediaPlayer` may have some error or warning lines that explain what it is not liking.

Comment: I updated the post with the logcat

Comment: No, I mean, scroll higher in LogCat than this, and look for messages from `MediaPlayer` that precede your crash.

Comment: Resolved: I change the sound file and it worked perfect, surely the file was in a format that is not supported in version 6 android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: change the sound file and it worked perfect, surely the file was in a format that is not supported in version 6 android.

Comment: was a .mp3 file (beep)